# Code to generate an error message with Actionscript 2 and Debug Flash Player?

Tags: debugging, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to verify that my debug Flash player is behaving as expected, and also to be able to experiment with code and see what kinds of run-time errors are visible to the user.  I just want some Actionscript 2 code that will show an error when the Debug Flash Player is used.  I tried things like dividing by zero, but that didn't work (it treated it as "Infinity").  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple error that is quite common to being shown in the debug player (even for pages that are supposed to be stable) are I/O errors. I’m not perfectly sure how this is done in ActionScript 2, as it’s been quite a while since I used it, but you could try to simply load an URL that does not exist.